# Problem with Lightning Knowledge in package

Tags: knowledge, package, lightning-knowledge

I'm developing a managed package in a dev org that uses Lightning Knowledge. My problem is that is seems impossible to include the Lightning Knowledge custom object rather than the old classic article type. The apex code in the package uses the Lightning Knowledge custom object API Name, but the classic article type API name is the same, and the package manager always decides to include (due to dependencies) the latter, not the former. Is there any workaround?

---

More details. This is the error I get when I try to install the managed package in another org that has Lightning Knowledge enabled:

[image: package error]

Another update. I've tried to use always record types when handling Knowledge records in my apex code to ensure that I'm using Lightning Knowledge objects, not classic. But even with that, "Article type" (classic) is added automatically to my package when I manually add the apex classes (dependency)

Answer (score 0):

Once we have enabled lightning knowledge in org, the Article Type field is no longer accessible via SOQL or the API, which affects custom code that queries for the ArticleType.  Workaround would be, If you have included Classic Knowledge Article Types as components in managed package the only option available is to remove the Knowledge components from the package and you should be able to install/deploy successfully.

Check more details on [Knowledge components in managed package](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000393774&type=1) along with [Lightning Knowledge Limitations](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.knowledge_lightning_limitations.htm&type=5).